# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar automáticamente una macros de Excel en segundo plano?

Tags: excel

Es posible ejecutar una macro en segundo plano? a manera que si se esta trabajando en otro proceso o aplicación, no interfiera al abrir el archivo y esperar a que lo cierre. Gracias, saludos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Yo creo que no, pero esperemos que otra persona lo confirme.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes abrir 2 instancias de Excel a la vez, de tal manera que en uno ejecutas la macro mientras en la otra instancia trabajas (influye mucho el equipo que tengas, ojo). Pero lo que no puedes hacer es tener abierto el mismo archivo en más de una instancia a la vez.

> [Abrir un segundo libro de otra copia de
> Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/abrir-un-segundo-libro-de-otra-copia-de-excel-921fa0db-cfc5-4548-8cd5-80e6333307d8)